# XSLT - Insert element at last position of parent

Tags: xml, xslt, insert, parent

Given XML

```
<SystemInfo> 
    <Info>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <ID>ZZ</ID>
        <Number>2332</Number>
        <Date>2020-10-10</Date>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
    </Info>
    <Info>
        <Name>XYZ</Name>
        <ID>ZZ</ID>
        <Number>1234</Number>
        <Date>2020-10-10</Date>
        <Ind>X</Ind>
    </Info>
    <Info>
        <Name>PQR</Name>
        <ID>ZZ</ID>
        <Number>1234</Number>
        <Date>2020-10-10</Date>
        <Ack>Y</Ack>
    </Info>
</SystemInfo>
```

The XSLT should add a new element as the last element of 'Info' tag only when Name = 'XYZ'
The expected output is as below.

```
<SystemInfo> 
    <Info>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <ID>ZZ</ID>
        <Number>2332</Number>
        <Date>2020-10-10</Date>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
    </Info>
    <Info>
        <Name>XYZ</Name>
        <ID>ZZ</ID>
        <Number>1234</Number>
        <Date>2020-10-10</Date>
        <Ind>X</Ind>
        **<Type>P</Type>**
    </Info>
    <Info>
        <Name>PQR</Name>
        <ID>ZZ</ID>
        <Number>1234</Number>
        <Date>2020-10-10</Date>
        <Ack>Y</Ack>
    </Info>
</SystemInfo>
```

I tried the below two ways.

First implementation.

```
<xsl:template match="/|@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-template select = "@*/node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:Info[./ns0:Name='XYZ']">
     <xsl:apply-template select = "@*/node()" />
     <xsl:element name="Type">P</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

--> Result >> misses the 'Info' tag when Name='XYZ'

Second implementation.

```
<xsl:template match="/|@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-template select = "@*/node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:Info[./ns0:Name='XYZ']">
     <xsl:copy-of select = "." />
     <xsl:element name="Type">P</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

--> Result >> 'Type' shows up below the 'Info' end-tag instead of above the end-tag

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to make minor changes to your template:

```
<xsl:template match="Info[Name='XYZ']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select = "@* | node()" />
        <xsl:element name="Type">P</xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If necessary, add the namespace `ns0:` to your match rule like this:

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:Info[ns0:Name='XYZ']"> 
...
```

And pay attention to the fact that your *Identity template* is incorrect. The correct one is the following:

```
<!-- Identity template -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SystemInfo>
  <Info>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <ID>ZZ</ID>
    <Number>2332</Number>
    <Date>2020-10-10</Date>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
  </Info>
  <Info>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <ID>ZZ</ID>
    <Number>1234</Number>
    <Date>2020-10-10</Date>
    <Ind>X</Ind>
    <Type>P</Type>           <!-- Added by template -->
  </Info>
  <Info>
    <Name>PQR</Name>
    <ID>ZZ</ID>
    <Number>1234</Number>
    <Date>2020-10-10</Date>
    <Ack>Y</Ack>
  </Info>
</SystemInfo>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick turnaround